# Filtering multiple columns in Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to filter multiple rows and columns in Google Sheets and show only the cells that match the value that I want, but so far I didn't have success.

Here goes a link with the raw data and the expected output that I need.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1355FJBYlzlU1RajWZ1Cj1qhXkRrU4QYegeQ4UzBeE3I/edit?usp=sharing

In this example, I wanna filter by activity and show only the days that I have a "Cycling" class, for instance. The filter needs to be a sort of dropdown since more people will be using it.

I tried to use the slicer feature, but it allows me to filter just 1 column and not multiple.

Any idea on how to make it?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. While including a like to a demo spreadsheet could be useful, all the relevant details should be included in the body of the question.

Comment: See the docs: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en. Sounds especially worth checking out filter views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({B3:F3; 
 IF(B4:F7<>"Cycling";;B4:F7)};;99^99)); " ")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: That's a good idea, however, how can I make it as a dropdown, where people can select one of those values (Cycling, Running, Swimming...) and then get it filtered based on the selection?

Comment: @DiegoFaria see this demo sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Iso3OucgM9fiU55eUqVmltaIYWPR3V8apI5N9G7XnoA/edit#gid=0